# What is the expansion of $1/(15+5z)$ valid for $|z|>3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Ok, I know this question is cheese! But I am stuck at this for the past two hours. Getting different answers after the expansion.
Here's what I know:
$1/(1-z) = -1/z -1/z^2 - \cdots$  valid for $|z|>1$.
This series will be used.

Comment: @IanMateus Unfortunately No! The series you wrote is valid for |z|<1 , the one i wrote is valid for |z|>1.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was too fast on that.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac{1}{15+5z} = \frac{1}{15} \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{3}} = \frac{1}{15} \frac{1}{1-\frac{-z}{3}}$$